# How to start my own altcoin based on Monero code?

Tags: altcoin

How can I start new altcoin based on Monero source?

Comment: Hey, don't create another Monero aka don't CAM.

Comment: what is CAM???..

Comment: Don't Create Another Monero.

Comment: why I shouldn't ?

Comment: There are a lot of reasons.

Comment: @SerHack The monero project states “There are no restrictions on anyone creating an alternative implementation of Monero that uses the protocol and network in a compatible manner” see - https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/master/README.md

Comment: @zigglzworth Sure! It was a my suggestion!

Comment: @SerHack I’m not sure what you mean by your ‘suggestion’? He asked about starting an altcoin based on Monero. This is acceptable according to the monero project as per the above link. So to reply with ‘Don’t CAM’ is not really in line with the philosophy of the project/team (and to an extent open source in general)

Comment: Hello, I was joking when I wrote Don't Cam. You can fork Monero without problems! Starting a new coin based on Monero isn't so difficult, but you need to know the Monero code.